# $E(\max_i X_i)/(n^{(1/\theta)})\to\infty$ for i.i.d sequence

Tags: probability-theory

For an i.i.d sequence $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ with p.d.f $f(x)=\theta x^{-(\theta+1)}\mathbf{1}_{x>1}$ where $\theta>1$. I am trying to show that $\frac{E[X_{(n)}]}{n^{\varepsilon}}\uparrow \infty$ where $\varepsilon<\frac{1}{\delta}$. Here $X_{(n)}$ is the usual maximum of the first $n$, $X_i's$
Attempt,
$$ {E X_{(n)}}=\int_1^\infty P(X_{(n)}> x)dx=\int_1^\infty 1-P(X_1\le x, X_2\le x,...,X_n\le x)dx=\int_1^\infty 1-P(X_1\le x)^n dx=\int_1^\infty  1-(1-x^{-\theta})^n dx.$$

I have arrived to form that cannot be integrated? of course it diverges if $n\to\infty$ on the inside, but cannot determine if indeed it does it grow faster than $n^\varepsilon$.

Comment: The indicator in the PDF should be $\mathbf{1}_{x > 1}$, right?

Comment: Yes thank you, it is now fixed.

Comment: You forgot to divide by $n^{1/\theta}$ and you also got the CDF wrong. $P(X_i \leq x)=1-x^{-\theta}$ for $x >1$.

Comment: I have fixed the errors but now the expression is not integrable?